# What kind/type was the 3D terrain editor of Warcraft 3's World Editor? How it worked?

Tags: architecture, procedural-generation, terrain, terrain-rendering, world-editor

Warcraft III (WC3) had a lovely map editor that allowed for a whole lot of stuff, [yes](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/150646/why-wouldnt-games-be-published-with-map-editors-included) *(this was the best result I could squeeze out of Google)*, but what to me stood out the most and what I played with the most, really, was its powerful yet easy to work with Terrain Editor.

It felt like playing with LEGO's... but better in some ways.

I remember even the first Starcraft had something similar, but of course, not as powerful as WC3, given how WC3 was Blizzard's first full-blown 3D rendered game.

To emphasize:

- It operated on a grid, yes, like a tilemap
- But it had varying heights (3D)
- It seemed to procedurally generate seams/transitions/cliffs/textures whatnot
- It also allowed for ramps
- Building with it was super simple and intuitive
- No janky heightmaps of varying heights (at least not directly, looking at you Unity)
- No CSG either? (Unreal / Source)
- No brush sensitivity
- You could only select given "biomes" to work with, but everything would fit to theme
- And boy was it performant... doesn't feel like every "cell" was a separate entity.
- It kind of felt voxely, but was it? Marching Cubes with low resolution?
- AI worked flawlessly atop of it (NavMeshes?)

If we were to classify it... what kind/type does it fall into? Any other editors operate like that? And then, how would one approach to build something like that?

Comment: Looks like you have a wonderous world to explore ahead of you, which is Gamedev. It may seem like a rocket-science, but once you start to dissect it you will realize that it is all built from simpler pieces all the way down (kinda like LEGO, yep).

Answer (score 1):

> how would one approach to build something like that?

First of all, you need a grid. And there is extra data per vertex - not per cell - of the grid.

Notably:

- How High the terrain is (this is a float). Thus, it is likely there is height map texture, or alternatively it is baked on the vertex position.
- To which Layer it belongs (this is an integer). While you could use the height to make smooth-ish hills, you would change the layer to make cliffs. And the cliff faces have additional geometry, depending on the type you pick. And, by the way: a ramp is a kind of cliff.
- Which kind of Tile it is. Apparently you draw like a tile map, with auto-tiling. This suggest we can use a render step to make a 2D tilemap, which would be the texture for the terrain (but not for the cliff additional geometry).

For water you probably need shallow and deep water masks, or a depth map (I mean, like a height map but for how deep the water is). Notably for shallow water we can make the terrain raise above the water level by changing its elevation.

The elevation of a vertex would be its height form the height map, plus the layer multiplied by the elevation of a cliff.

Since I'm saying to use addition custom geometry to make the cliff faces, that would also hide their change in elevation. This way the geometry for a ramp is: none. *Another idea would be able to mark vertex to be discarded.*

Picking the geometry build the cliff faces could work similar to auto-tiling, or marching squares. *We certainly don't need something as complex as marching cubes*.

I want to note that the game is able to animate the high of vertex during game play, and it would also move the cliffs. *This is something a vertex shader could do.*

Also note that the editor must be maintaining a navigation mesh. For example if you pick a cliff it will disconnect the navigation, unless it is a ramp. Also, I believe placing bridges would have had to update the navigation mesh.

And of course there are entities placed on the map such as trees, building, etc... Plus we could vary entities according to the terrain where you are placing them.

---

And your other questions:

> If we were to classify it... what kind/type does it fall into?

It is a map editor. And a map is not just a terrain. There is a combination of techniques applied to make it. *It is easier to think out side any proverbial box if you don't put things in boxes to begin with.*

> Any other editors operate like that?

I'm unaware of any non blizzard one. It seems they evolved their solution along the development of multiple games.